# Entity Framework: How To Update Children Without Re-Adding Parents

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, savechanges

I have the following C# pseudo-code:

```
public void TestFunc(int ParentId)
{
    using DBContext Context = new DBContext();
    Parent X = Context.Parents.Find(ParentId);
    X.CreateChild();
    Context.SaveChanges();
}

public class CategoryDetail
{
    public int Id;
    public Category ParentCategory {get; set;}
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id;
    public List<CategoryDetail> CategoryDetails {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id;
    public CategoryDetail ThisCategoryDetail {get; set;}
    public Parent ThisParent {get; set;}
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id;
    public Category ThisCategory {get; set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get; set;}

    public CreateChild()
    {
        Child NewChild = new Child();
        NewChild.ThisCategoryDetail = ThisCategory.CategoryDetails[0];
        NewChild.ThisParent = this;

        Children.Add(NewChild);
    }
}
```

Each Category contains a number of CategoryDetail elements.

Each Parent contains a number of children and is a member of a particular Category.

Each Child contains a pointer back to its Parent as well as a pointer to a particular CategoryDetail element.

When I run the CreateChild method, the Context becomes full of added references back to the Category and its CategoryDetail elements.  When the Context tries to save the changes, it complains that it already has an existing reference back to the these items.

I can see in the Context.ChangeTracker that, indeed, elements exist more than once in an added state.

I have tried any number of schemes to make sure this doesn't happen, but have not succeeded yet.  I have tried manually changing the state of the other items to unchanged, etc., but can't seem to find the way to do this without running into one wall or another.

How can I keep the context 'clean'?

Comment: Could you also post your `DBContext`, and the method in which you are creating/retrieving the Parent and calling `CreateChild`

Comment: It's a distillation of a very complex system that I won't be able to repro here.  But in brief, the problem occurs because both the child and parent contain references to the same object, the Category.  This causes the Category to be loaded multiple times into the Context, some times with its State set to Added.  Then SaveChanges complains because it already exists in the database with the same Id and can't be added again.

Comment: We cannot see where your Category is loaded. If it's loaded multiple times, you very likely use multiple instances of your context - otherwise this wouldn't happen.

Comment: OK.  I added some code at the top of the listing to demonstrate:  When I call TestFunc, it finds a parent and at that point loads an unmodified version of a Category into the context.  Then when the CreateChild function is called, a second occurrence of Category is loaded into the context, but in this case it's marked as 'Added'.  That's where the conflict occurs.

Comment: 1)  I keep changing the code here to reflect comments by people.  I have pulled the Context from CreateChild.  It was sufficient in the TestFunc method.

2)  What would the pattern be for creating a child that's wholly dependent on its parent for its existence?